# Drupal facebook and twitter oAuth2 500 error

Tags: facebook, twitter, drupal

I have a site on drupal that pull some data from Facebook and Twitter with Oauth2, it was working fine but after an update it looks like it stoped working.

When I update facebook I get an error like:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=123456&op=do StatusText: Internal Server Error ResponseText:
```

The twitter one just simply show a white error page with a 500 message, any ideas on how I can troubleshot this?

Answer (score 0):

A missing library was the reason for this (jsonpath.php) .

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser